# Strange way to pass data between modules in Python: How does it work?

Tags: python, class, instance, interpreter

I'm supposed to work with some messy code that I haven't written myself, and amidst the mess I found out two scripts that communicate by this strange fashion (via a 3rd middleman script):

`message.py`, the 'middleman' script:

```
class m():
    pass
```

`sender.py`, who wants to send some info to the receiver:

```
from message import m

someCalculationResult = 1 + 2
m.result = someCalculationResult
```

`receiver.py`, who wants to print some results produced by `sender.py`:

```
from message import m

mInstance = m()
print mInstance.result
```

And, by magic, in the interpreter, importing `sender.py` then `receiver.py` does indeed print 3...

Now, what the hell is happening behind the scenes here? Are we storing our results into the class definition itself and recovering them via a particular instance? If so, why can't we recover the results from the definition itself also? Is there a more elegant way to pass stuff inbetween scripts ran sucessively in the interpreter?

Using Python 2.6.6

Comment: "If so, why can't we recover the results from the definition itself also?" - you can. Making an instance is unnecessary, but then again, the whole class is unnecessary too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just a convoluted way to set a global.

`m` is a class, `m.result` a class attribute. Both the sender and receiver can access it directly, just as they can access `m`.

They could have done this too:

```
# sender
import message
message.result = someCalculationResult

# receiver
import message
print message.result
```

Here `result` is just a name in the `message` module top-level module.

It should be noted that what you are doing is *not* running separate scripts; you are importing modules into the same interpreter. If you ran `python sender.py` first, without ever importing `reciever.py`, then separately running `python receiver.py` without ever importing `sender.py` this whole scheme doesn't work.

There are myriad ways to pass data from one section of code to another section, too many to name here, all fitting for a different scenario and need. Threading, separate processes, separate *computers* all introduce different constraints on how message passing can and should take place, for example.

Comment: I see, I was complicating a simple thing. Guess the fact that sometimes in the code the message was instantiated and others not added to my confusion. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: Just one more question: If I  have this really expensive sender.py script (which I only want to run once) and another receiver.py which I want to be constantly editing and running (using results from sender.py), how do I achieve this? If I import sender on receiver it will execute the expensive script again... (hope I was clear) (EDIT: I guess using the interpreter does it, but just in case I wanted to do it outside, really running scripts like you said)

Comment: You could use a simple database file (`sqlite` can make this easy if you know SQL) to store messages. Or use some form of inter-process communication. Or a file your sender writes to (locking it before it does so) and your receiver reads from. Etc. etc. etc. There are many ways to do this, too many to name here.